# How to navigate to another fragment using Navcontroller after clicking on cardview?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-cardview

I have various Cardviews and I want to go to specific fragments of each after I click on them. I am using Navigation graph and i want to use NavController for going to another fragment. I am trying to use Navigation but I am simply missing something. Below is my code.
FlashcardsAdapter.kt

```
class FlashcardsAdapter(private val imageList: List<FlashCardInfo>) :RecyclerView.Adapter<FlashcardsAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val imageViewFlashcards = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.id.imageViewFlashcards)
        val textViewFlashcards = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.id.textflashCardName)
        val textViewFlashcardsLithuanian = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.id.textflashCardLithuanian)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.layout.item_flashcards, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current_item = imageList[position]

        holder.imageViewFlashcards.setImageResource(current_item.imageId)
        holder.textViewFlashcards.text = current_item.name
        holder.textViewFlashcardsLithuanian.text = current_item.translation

        val imageFlashcards = holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.id.imageViewFlashcards)
        val textViewFlashCards = holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.id.textflashCardName)
        val cardviewFlashcard = holder.itemView.findViewById<CardView>(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.id.cardFlashCards)
        val textLithuanian = holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(com.example.visuallithuanian.R.id.textflashCardLithuanian)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return imageList.size
    }
}
```

Flashcards.kt

```
class FlashCards : Fragment() {

    lateinit var bottomNav:BottomNavigationView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_flash_cards, container, false)

        //Taking the bOTTOMNavigation view instance from Activity into Fragment
        bottomNav = (activity as? FirstScreen)?.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView)!!
        bottomNav.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        val back_icon = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.back_icon)
        val recyclerViewCards1 = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerViewFlashcards)

        recyclerViewCards1.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(),
            R.id.nav_host_fragment
        )

        val flashCardList = generateFlashCards()
        val adapter = FlashcardsAdapter(flashCardList)
        recyclerViewCards1.adapter = adapter


        // setting up listener
        back_icon.setOnClickListener {
            activity?.onBackPressed()
        }

        return view
    }

    private fun generateFlashCards():List<FlashCardInfo> {
        return listOf(
            FlashCardInfo(R.drawable.talking,"Daily Conversation","Kasdienis pokalbis"),
            FlashCardInfo(R.drawable.doctorvisit,"Questions and Pronouns","Klausimai ir įvardžiai"),
            FlashCardInfo(R.drawable.food,"Food","Maistas"),
            FlashCardInfo(R.drawable.relatives,"Relatives","Giminaičiai"),
            FlashCardInfo(R.drawable.clothing,"Clothing","Drabužiai"),
            FlashCardInfo(R.drawable.village,"Towns and Villages","Miestai ir kaimai"),
            FlashCardInfo(R.drawable.nature,"Nature","Gamta"),
            FlashCardInfo(R.drawable.verbs,"Popular Verbs","Populiariausi veiksmažodžiai"),
        )

    }
```

Here all the elements in list are cardview elemnts and for each I have a fragment.
Below is my xml layout files.

fragments_flash_cards.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flash_tablebar"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/relativeFlashcard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/back_icon"
            >
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:text="Flashcards"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subtext_flash"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_below="@id/title_text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:text="Pick a set to practice"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#FFF" />
        </RelativeLayout>



    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewFlashcards"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

item_flashcards.xml

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/cardFlashCards"
            app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/flashcard_color"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewFlashcards"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:background="@drawable/circular_flashcardview" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textflashCardName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Text1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textflashCardLithuanian"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Text2"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Try referring to this: https://youtu.be/bawjkQoIYt8

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `CLickListener` which is set on all items via the `Adapter` when binding the `ViewHolders`. When clicking an item, the `FlashFragment` is notified and can then handle the navigation to the next `Fragment`.

```
class FlashcardsAdapter(
      private val imageList: List<FlashCardInfo>,
      private val onFlashCardClicked: (FlashCardInfo) -> Unit
) : ... {

      override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current_item = imageList[position]

        holder.imageViewFlashcards.setImageResource(current_item.imageId)
        holder.textViewFlashcards.text = current_item.name
        holder.textViewFlashcardsLithuanian.text = current_item.translation

        ...

        val cardviewFlashcard = ...
        cardviewFlashcard.setOnClickListener { onFlashCardClicked(current_item) }
    }

}



class FlashCards : Fragment() {

  override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
  ): View? {
     ...

     val adapter = FlashcardsAdapter(flashCardList){
         // navigate to Fragment based on FlashCardInfo
     }
  }
}
```

You can simplify your Adapter by using [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter). It provides base handling for a list of data inside `RecyclerView`.